# Regex with end of line in group

Tags: python, regex

Given this kind of input:

```
.-[ 127.0.0.1/44963 -> 127.0.0.1/502 (syn+ack) ]-
|
| server   = 127.0.0.1/502
| os       = ???
| dist     = 0
| params   = none
| raw_sig  = 4:64+0:0:0:32768,0:::0
|
`----

.-[ 127.0.0.1/44963 -> 127.0.0.1/502 (syn+ack) ]-
|
| server   = 127.0.0.1/502
| os       = ???
| dist     = 0
| params   = none
| raw_sig  = 4:64+0:0:0:32768,0:::0
|
`----
...
```

I'm trying use regex to get the value of all the `os` in the output (there will be hundreds).

I've tried this:

```
import os, subprocess, re

dir = '/home/user/Documents/ics-passif-asset-enumeration/pcap/'

for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    inp = '...'
    match = re.match( r'(.*)os(.*)\n(.*)', inp  )
    print match.group(1)
```

But match is a `NoneType`. Never really played with regex before and I'm a bit lost.

Edit:

The expected output is a list of all the `os` values. In this case it would be:

```
???
???
```

Comment: I don't see any `os` in `inp = '...'` :/

Comment: Is there only one entry per file, or could each file have multiple entries in which you'll extract 'os' out of ?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R the `...` was simply for posting on stack overflow. The var is actually loaded from a file in my script and is hundreds of lines long (similar to what's shown in the first snippet in the post)

Comment: @brandon.bell There will be multiple `os` entries per file

Comment: So, do you want an array which contains the values of each `os` in sequence?

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R sorry you are right I should've been clear about the expected output, it should be an array of all the OS values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
>>> import re
>>> string = """.-[ 127.0.0.1/44963 -> 127.0.0.1/502 (syn+ack) ]-
... |
... | server   = 127.0.0.1/502
... | os       = ???
... | dist     = 0
... | params   = none
... | raw_sig  = 4:64+0:0:0:32768,0:::0
... |
... `----"""
>>> match = re.match( r'(.*)os\s*=(.*?)\n', string, re.DOTALL)
>>> match.group(2)
' ???'
```

**Changes made**

- `re.DOTALL` This flag is required so that you are trying to match multiline inputs.
- `os\s*=(.*?)`

  - `\s*=` The `=` and spaces are made out of the capture group since we are not interested in them.
  - `(.*?)` The `?` makes it non greedy so that it matches till the end of the first line
- `match.group(2)` it is the second match group not the first.

---

**A better and short solution**

You can use the [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.findall) with slighter different regex

```
os\s*=(.*)
```

**Test**

```
>>> string = """.-[ 127.0.0.1/44963 -> 127.0.0.1/502 (syn+ack) ]-
... |
... | server   = 127.0.0.1/502
... | os       = ???
... | dist     = 0
... | params   = none
... | raw_sig  = 4:64+0:0:0:32768,0:::0
... |
... `----
... 
... .-[ 127.0.0.1/44963 -> 127.0.0.1/502 (syn+ack) ]-
... |
... | server   = 127.0.0.1/502
... | os       = ???
... | dist     = 0
... | params   = none
... | raw_sig  = 4:64+0:0:0:32768,0:::0
... |
... `----
... ..."""

>>> re.findall(r"os\s*=(.*)", string)
[' ???', ' ???']
```

Comment: sorry you are right I should've been clear about the expected output, it should be an array of all the OS values

Comment: Why using a capture group at first (I mean the first one before os) ? (I had understood an atomic group to avoid the backtracking, but can't see the interest of the capture group if it's not used later)

Comment: @Tensibai That regex is really messy, I just modified a little to demonstrate OP how it can be changed to produce the expected output. I have also included a better solution with another regex

Answer (score 2):

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.findall) will return an array of results! Fantastic! Assuming the format of your input is pretty consistent, this should work like a charm:

```
>>> inp = '''
... .-[ 127.0.0.1/44963 -> 127.0.0.1/502 (syn+ack) ]-
... |
... | server   = 127.0.0.1/502
... | os       = ???
... | dist     = 0
... | params   = none
... | raw_sig  = 4:64+0:0:0:32768,0:::0
... |
... `----
... 
... .-[ 127.0.0.1/44963 -> 127.0.0.1/502 (syn+ack) ]-
... |
... | server   = 127.0.0.1/502
... | os       = ???
... | dist     = 0
... | params   = none
... | raw_sig  = 4:64+0:0:0:32768,0:::0
... |
... `----
... ...
... '''
>>> re.findall(r'^| os\s+= (.*)$', inp, flags=re.MULTILINE)
['???', '???']
```

I agree with the idea that the format should be strict to ensure that the string won't appear somewhere else. If this all came from a script then the strictness shouldn't be a problem (you'd hope). If it was via manual entry... I'd be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

For the dot operator (.) to match newlines, add a flag to the match-call:

```
match = re.match( r'(.*)os(.*)\n(.*)', inp, flags=re.DOTALL  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you wished (and assuming your input is what you copied here (multiline, multientry) this regex should do with modifier `gm` to match all and let ^ and $ match respectively start and end of line:

`^|\s*os\s*=\s*(.*)$`

Demo [Here](https://regex101.com/r/tC5zE2/1)

Answer (score 0):

You may try use findall() method:

```
for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    inp = '...'
    match = re.findall('os(.*)\n', inp)
    print match
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Tensibai says, you're probably best to use `^` and `$` to match the start and end of the line, and a very specific pattern (as he gives) to make sure that the string "os" is not matched somewhere else, like within a hostname for example.

To directly find all of the matching "os = " lines, use `re.findall( r'^|\s*os\s*=\s*(.*)$', inp, re.MULTILINE )`, which returns a list of the matching os values.

Comment: You'll need the `MULTILINE` flag there, won't you?

Comment: Yes, good catch, @BilalAkil.  Should be `re.findall(r'^|\s*os\s*=\s*(.*)$', inp, re.MULTILINE)`